# Dynamic width modal?

Tags: vue.js

I've been playing around with the Vue.js modal demo here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html. It allows me to insert the content I want to display as a modal dialog via slots, which is handy. The one downside is that the modal is fixed width, set via CSS within the Modal component. It would be more versatile for me if the width were dynamic, determined by the width of the content I'm passing in to the body slot.

I've made it a little more flexible by adding a 'width' prop and this as mounted, so that the size can be set by the parent component:

```
mounted(){
  if(this.width) {
     $(".vue-modal .modal-container").css("width", this.width);
  }
}
```

It's still not dynamic, though, of course, I'm just passing in a fixed size. I'm wondering whether anyone has any ideas for getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is to override the provided classes. As opposed to using a `display: table-cell` on the `modal-wrapper`, you can instead use a flexbox:

```
.modal-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then, on the `modal-container` you just need to set the `display` to `inline-block` and the `width` to `auto`:

```
.modal-container{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
```

[Here's your JSfiddle link based on VueJS's example](https://jsfiddle.net/k7mqez7u/)

Comment: That is excellent, and should, in my opinion, replace the VueJS example, as it's more versatile and usable as a result. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnMoore display table:cell is more widely supported. IE 10/9 do not support it, and 11 is still a bit buggy. Although [most other major browsers provide native support](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Although I don't personally care to support any IE browser, so for me this is fine.